# HQL query based on logical condition

Tags: hadoop, hql, logical-operators, bigdata

Right now I am keeping multiple .hql file for each table present on my database for ex: **.hql**. And then I am executing it from shell script based on table name I found as a param.

For ex: `hive -F -s <table_name_from_param>.hql`

So now, what I want is to keep all these .hql files queries in one .hql file and then some how I want put a logical condition based on which only respective hql query will execute.

Let say the new .hql file is: `script.hql`, where contents of that file will be something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name_1> = "somevalue"

SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name_2> = "somevalue"

SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name_2> = "somevalue"
```

So now I want to only execute one query based on table name.

Comment: **So now I want to only execute one query based on table name.** can you pls explain this ?

Comment: As per above example I have 4 queries in one .hql file. So if I will execute `hive -F -s --hiveconf tablename="firstTable" <table_name_from_param>.hql`, then it should only execute first query from the .hql file.

Comment: So some how I have to put logical condition in .hql file.

Comment: Can you create 4 files and trigger it as per condition in shell?